# How to remove rows matching criteria and rows adjacent to them

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following sample data:

```
data <- data.table(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4), 
                 date = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6), 
                score = c(4,3,2,2,4,1,5,5,5,2,1,4,2,1,5,5,5,3,5,5,5,2,4,5))

   ID date score
 1:  1    1     4
 2:  1    2     3
 3:  1    3     2
 4:  1    4     2
 5:  1    5     4
 6:  1    6     1
 7:  2    1     5
 8:  2    2     5
 9:  2    3     5
10:  2    4     2
11:  2    5     1
12:  2    6     4
13:  3    1     2
14:  3    2     1
15:  3    3     5
16:  3    4     5
17:  3    5     5
18:  3    6     3
19:  4    1     5
20:  4    2     5
21:  4    3     5
22:  4    4     2
23:  4    5     4
24:  4    6     5
    ID date score
```

I want to eliminate certain rows, and change others, based in part on their position in the table. I have two criteria, for each `ID`:

1. If a row has `date == 1` and `score == 5`, I want to remove that row AND all subsequent rows that have `score==5` that follow immediately after that row, until `score` is not 5. (so, for example, for `I == 4`, I want to keep the data for dates 4,5,6).
2. For all other dates where `score == 5`, I want to replace their score with the average of their preceding two scores (or just their previous score, if they only have one prior score).

So, the table I want to end up with is:

```
   ID date score
 1:  1    1   4.0
 2:  1    2   3.0
 3:  1    3   2.0
 4:  1    4   2.0
 5:  1    5   4.0
 6:  1    6   1.0
 7:  2    4   2.0
 8:  2    5   1.0
 9:  2    6   4.0
10:  3    1   2.0
11:  3    2   1.0
12:  3    3   1.5
13:  3    4   1.5
14:  3    5   1.5
15:  3    6   3.0
16:  4    4   2.0
17:  4    5   4.0
18:  4    6   3.0
```

What is the best way to go about this? I imagine it's some combination of `shift` and `.I` but I haven't been able to put it together.

Comment: For the first part, you could do `data[, if(date[1L] == 1L) .SD[which.max(score != 5L):.N], by = ID]` maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# find rows satisfying 1st condition
torm = data[, if(score[1] == 5 & date[1] == 1) .I
            , by = .(ID, rleid(score), cumsum(date == 1))]$V1

library(caTools) # for running mean

data[-torm    # remove the extra rows
   # add a running mean
   ][, mn := runmean(score, 2, endrule = 'keep', align = 'right'), by = ID
   # compute the new score - a little care needed here in case we only have 5's in a group
   ][, new.score := ifelse(score == 5, mn[which(score != 5)[1]], score)
     , by = .(ID, cumsum(score != 5))][]
#    ID date score  mn new.score
# 1:  1    1     4 4.0       4.0
# 2:  1    2     3 3.5       3.0
# 3:  1    3     2 2.5       2.0
# 4:  1    4     2 2.0       2.0
# 5:  1    5     4 3.0       4.0
# 6:  1    6     1 2.5       1.0
# 7:  2    4     2 2.0       2.0
# 8:  2    5     1 1.5       1.0
# 9:  2    6     4 2.5       4.0
#10:  3    1     2 2.0       2.0
#11:  3    2     1 1.5       1.0
#12:  3    3     5 3.0       1.5
#13:  3    4     5 5.0       1.5
#14:  3    5     5 5.0       1.5
#15:  3    6     3 4.0       3.0
#16:  4    4     2 2.0       2.0
#17:  4    5     4 3.0       4.0
#18:  4    6     5 4.5       3.0
```

Comment: This does the trick, although I had to use `endrule = 'mean'` to get exactly what I wanted (in my non-example use I wanted a run mean window of 5, so when there were fewer than 5 to look at I wanted a mean of whatever was there, not just the most recent one). Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

With `na.locf` from `zoo` package:

```
library(zoo)

DF <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4), 
                 date = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6), 
                score = c(4,3,2,2,4,1,5,5,5,2,1,4,2,1,5,5,5,3,5,5,5,2,4,5))



#mark rows for deletion

DF$markForDel=NA

DF$markForDel[DF$date==1 & DF$score==5]=1

DF$markForDel[DF$score!=5]=0

DF$markForDel = zoo::na.locf(DF$markForDel)


newDF = DF[DF$markForDel!=1,]
rownames(newDF)=NULL


#impute mean of previous score where score == 5
newDF$score[newDF$score==5]=NA

newDF$imputedScore = sapply(1:nrow(newDF),function(x)  {
ifelse(x>3 & is.na(newDF$score[x]),mean(c(newDF$score[x-1],newDF$score[x-2]) ),newDF$score[x]) })               


newDF$imputedScore = zoo::na.locf(newDF$imputedScore)
```

**Output:**

```
newDF
#   ID date score markForDel imputedScore
#1   1    1     4          0          4.0
#2   1    2     3          0          3.0
#3   1    3     2          0          2.0
#4   1    4     2          0          2.0
#5   1    5     4          0          4.0
#6   1    6     1          0          1.0
#7   2    4     2          0          2.0
#8   2    5     1          0          1.0
#9   2    6     4          0          4.0
#10  3    1     2          0          2.0
#11  3    2     1          0          1.0
#12  3    3    NA          0          1.5
#13  3    4    NA          0          1.5
#14  3    5    NA          0          1.5
#15  3    6     3          0          3.0
#16  4    4     2          0          2.0
#17  4    5     4          0          4.0
#18  4    6    NA          0          3.0
```

Comment: This doesn't satisfy either criteria, since none of this is per ID.